# Rate of convergence of the difference of two exponentials

Tags: convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I would like to find the convergence rate of the following function:

$$f(x) = |e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}|,$$

with $a,b>0$ and $x\to+\infty$. By finding the convergence rate, I mean finding the largest possible $c>0$ such that

$$f(x)\le k e^{-cx}\quad \forall x\ge x_0$$

for some $k>0$ and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. Of course the inequality holds for $c:=\min\{a,b\}$; but is that the largest possible $c$? And if so, how can we show that?

Comment: Yes, $c$ is equal to the smallest of the pair ${a, b}$. To see this, let us assume a is the smallest, then write $f(x) = e^{-ax}*abs(1-e^{-(b-a)x})$. In the limit of x to infinity the second term converges to 1. Of course the case $a = b$ is different!

Answer (score 1):

Assume without loss of generality that $0<a<b$. Then
$$
|e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}|=e^{-ax}\,\bigl|1-e^{-(b-a)x}\bigr|.
$$
Since $b-a>0$, we have
$$
1-e^{-(b-a)}\le1-e^{-(b-a)x}\le1,\quad x\ge1.
$$

Comment: As far as I understand, this shows that the inequality is satisfied by $c:=a$ with $k=1$ and $x_0=1$. But my question was: "is $c:=\min\{a,b\}$ the largest possible $c$ satisfying the condition, or can there be some larger $c$ that satisfy it? If $\min\{a,b\}$ is the largest possible $c$, how can we show that any larger $c$ would fail the condition?".

Comment: The answer is yes from the lower bound.